# In an ASP.NET app execute methods on multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have an ASP.NET app, where a single request invokes 6 very slow methods. The methods are not async and I don't have the time to rewrite and test them. How can I run those 6 methods on 6 threads and then agregate the results? I'm on .NET 4.5.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Take a look at the [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx). You can use it with [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to run background tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `Task.Run` to create a task that runs each of the methods in another thread, and then  wait for them all to finish so that you can use the results.

```
var tasks = new Task<YourResultType>[]
{
    Task.Run(() => Method1()),
    Task.Run(() => Method2()),
    Task.Run(() => Method3()),
    Task.Run(() => Method4()),
    Task.Run(() => Method5()),
    Task.Run(() => Method6()),
};

var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
```

If the methods don't all have results of the same type, allowing you to put all of the tasks into an array, then you'll need to have separate local variables for each task and use `Result` on each one after starting them all.