# Alternative to Task.ContinueWith

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm using the following wrapper around `Task.Run` to run a task and measure how long it took:

```
private static Task<MyObject> RunTask(Func<MyObject> task)
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var result = Task.Run(task);
    result.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        watch.Stop();
        t.Result.ExecutionTimeInMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    });
    return result;
}
```

I've seen many times the advice to avoid `ContinueWith` and instead use `await`. Can you help me do that?

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510707/in-an-asp-net-app-execute-methods-on-multiple-threads

Comment: So you don't plan on awaiting the returned task right away, right?

Comment: A have an array of Funcs, and do `Task.WhenAll(array.Select(RunTask)).Result`

Comment: Since nothing is really asynchronous here I think Parallel.Foreach would be clearer and possibly more performant.

Comment: The accuracy is limited since it's unknown when the continuation continues. You can fix that by specifying [TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather simple. You need to use the `async` modifier in your method and `await` on `Task.Run`:

```
private static async Task<MyObject> RunTask(Func<MyObject> task)
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var result = await Task.Run(task);
    watch.Stop();
    result.ExecutionTimeInMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    return result;
}
```